# add a datatable column that contains a url with arguments

Tags: datatables

I want to create a column containing a link with a url adding some arguments using 2 columns. For example "key" and "otherdata".

a link with some url with arguments like this: url?ticket=key&&type=otherdata

So far I was able to add one column using "render" option to create a link with one argument but I would like to add "otherdata" column as a second argument (instead of type=1 something like type=otherdata).

I have

```
"columns": [
{ "data": "otherdata"},   
{ "data": "key",
              "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return '<a class="link" style="text-decoration: underline;" href="http:uuu.com/myurl.aspx?ticket='+ data +'&type=1"'+ ' target="blank">' + data + '</a>';
 },
etc
```

I am new with Datatable, I would appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have everything you need right there.
Since you have data:"key"  in your columns, fundction(data, type, row) data is the key value.  The entire dataset for the row is contained in the row object. That would include row.key and row.otherdata.  So your code could look something like (for example)

```
   "columns": [
    { "data": "otherdata"},   
    { "data": "key"},
    { "defaultContent":"",
    "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return '<a class="link" style="text-decoration: underline;"' +    
           'href="http:uuu.com/myurl.aspx?ticket='+ row.key+'&type=1"'+ ' target="blank">' + row.otherdata + '</a>';
        }
    },
```